# Как записать данные в файл .JSON при помощи JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, сервер

Возможно ли при помощи локального сервера записывать данные с HTML-страницы в файл JSON на свой компьютер? Если возможно, то каким образом? Ориентируюсь на JavaScript, с PHP не знаком.

Comment: Вряд ли. По-моему, можно только создать, а что бы редактировать - нет. Хотя можно прочитать файл, редактировать его и создать новый с новым значениями

Comment: Собственно это и нужно, только каким образом?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью локального сервера возможно всё.

Берёшь nodejs, поднимаешь на нём сервер, при необходимости настраиваешь заголовки кроссдоменности (ну либо не настраиваешь, если страницу тоже он раздаёт), делаешь обработку запроса по определённому url, в которой сохраняешь файл.

Из скрипта обращаешься к соответствующему адресу и передаёшь желаемый json.

Answer (score 0):

А можно использовать [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)